# Taylor Polynomial: Why isn't the remainder function = to difference between the f(x)-p(x)?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, taylor-expansion

Trying to estimating $\ln(1.6)$ using a Taylor polynomial about $x=1$ to find the least degree of the polynomial that assures an error smaller than 0.001.

1. Using the formula $R_n \leq 0.001,R_n = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(z)}{(n+1)!}*(x-c)^{(n+1)}$
   $R_n$ when evaluated at n=7, x = 1.6, c=1, z = 1 because that gives the largest error  bound gives 0.000299931 ([WolframAlpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Divide%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B720%2C1%5D%5C%2841%29%2C8%21%5D*Power%5B0.6%2C8%5D))
2. But when I graph out the polynomials against the ln(x) function, the difference between $f(x) - p_{7}(x)= \ln(1.6) - 0.47137|=0.00136637...$ which should also give the difference/remainder(?), but it seems completely off.

Where is my knowledge gap/wrong assumption here?

Zoomed out for context:
[image]

Zoomed in for accuracy:
[image]

Comment: the remainder has a $\max_\zeta f^{(n+1)}(\zeta)$ inside

Comment: I get $0.6^8/8=0.00209952$ for the maximum

Comment: @Exodd yes, his z is your $\zeta$, he takes as 1 because that maximizes the derivative.

Comment: You have used the 7th derivative of $f$ in the WolframAlpha link, instead of the 8th derivative. The 8th derivative of $\ln(z)$ is $-7!z^{-8}$

Comment: @ReinhardMeier, thanks! I did add another term, but the difference (0.000733629) still wasn't anywhere close to 0.00029931..? Links::: WolframApha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cln%281.6%29-0.46927%7C
Graph(also added another term to get n=7): https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3wmp5s0sd4

Comment: @nvs0000 The calculation of the error is wrong, not the calculation of the truncated series. If you use $n=7$, it means that you truncate after the term with $(x-c)^7$, and you have to use the 8th derivative and $(x-c)^8$ in the calculation of the maximum error. The number 0.00029931 must not appear anywhere. The correct value (in case of $n=7$) is given in Empy2's comment - which is a pretty good upper bound for the real error, which is approx. $0.00137$

Comment: By the way, you have rather big round-off errors in your calculation. For $n=8$ the real error is approx. $0.0007280635$ instead of $0.000733629.$ That is a wrong digit already at the second significant position. Do not truncate intermediate results too early, if this truncation basically cuts off everything that is significant for subsequent calculations.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier, I'm abit confused if the formula (bullet 1) wrong or the Taylor polynomial(bullet 2) wrong.

Comment: For **bullet point 1**, I was trying to get n=7. Because the formula states n+1. $R_n \leq 0.001,R_n = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(z)}{(n+1)!}*(x-c)^{(n+1)}$ are you saying I'm using the formula wrongly [here?](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=%7CDivide%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B720%2CPower%5B1%2C7%5D%5D%5C%2841%29%2C%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%297%5C%2841%29%2B1%5C%2841%29%21%5D*Power%5B0.6%2C%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%297%5C%2841%29%2B1%5C%2841%29%5D%7C) If so can you show me how to use it correctly? what @Empy2 did was missing half a chunk of the formula it seems, missing $\frac{f^{(n+1)}(z)}{((7)+1)!}$

Comment: Yes, the $720$ is wrong. It must be $5040,$ because it is supposed to be the 8th derivative.

Comment: Why would we take 8th derivative when we want n=7? Is the formula is $R_n = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(z)}{(n+1)!}*(x-c)^{(n+1)}$ wrong? (where $f^{(n+1)}(z)$ is the derivative at z = 1)

Comment: We are talking about $n=7.$ In this case $f^{(n+1)}$ is the 8th derivative. This is what the $(n+1)$ on the top-right side of the $f$ expresses.

Comment: Oh. and I took the 7th derivative instead of the 8th (which then remainder using the formula works out to be 0.00209952). It just clicked, sorry. Let me go work out those sums and see if they match.... Is it fair to assume the remainder using that formula = difference between f(x)-p(x)?

Comment: Exact equality holds for at least one $z$ between $c$ and $x,$ but we do not know which one. Therefore, we know that the error is at most as large as the maximum of the values we get when $z$ attains all values between $c$ and $x.$

Comment: Thanks again. So for **bullet point 2** sticking with n=7, which is 7th degree taylor polynomial we got $|f(x)-p_7(x)| = |\ln (1.6) - 0.47137|= 0.00136637$ Why is that so far away from our max error value 0.00209952...? Is that normal?.. FYI: I used [this](https://ibb.co/gZ4mpvc) for my calculations to get 0.47137

Comment: @ReinhardMeier, I did that again with wolframalpha, also got 0.47137 for the 7th degree taylor polynomial evaluated at x=1.6 [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Log%5B1%5D+%2B+1%2F1+%28x+-+1%29%5E1+%2B+-%281%2F1%5E2%29%2F2%21+%28x+-+1%29%5E2+%2B+2%2F1%5E3%2F3%21+%28x+-+1%29%5E3+%2B+-%286%2F1%5E4%29%2F4%21+%28x+-+1%29%5E4+%2B+24%2F1%5E5%2F5%21+%28x+-+1%29%5E5%2B+-120%2F1%5E6%2F6%21+%28x+-+1%29%5E6%2B+720%2F1%5E7%2F7%21+%28x+-+1%29%5E7%2C+x%3D1.6)